# How to set id in anchor tag using rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody please help me to set id in the anchor tag link as query string.My working anchor tag line is given below.I want to add "current_user.id" as query string with it.

```
<a href="/homes/magazines">Magazines Purchase</a>
```

I am using rails version 3.2.19 and ruby version 1.9.3.

Comment: `<a href="/homes/magazines?user_id=<%= current_user.id %>">Magazines Purchase</a>`

Comment: Any reason you aren't using rails' `link_to` helper? [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: If you are using `rails` then you should follow `rails standards` like use `helpers` for generating `tag`.